# Delete multiple resource service python-eve

Tags: eve

I'm using python eve 0.62 and I try to delete multiple items from a collections:

this is what im doing:

```
  http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/Images?where={"_id": {"$in":["a","b"]}}
```

where the request method is:

```
 Request Method:DELETE
```

**Result:**

This delete all the resource in the collection :( , not only the id in the list

**My question is:**

As I read from the python eve documentation, Delete can be used as Collection:

Delete  DELETE  **Collection**/Document

http://python-eve.org/features.html

How i have do do if I want to delete few resources by id?

Answer (score 1):

`DELETE` performed at the resource endpoint is currently designed to wipe all the documents. This is also the reason why it is usually a smart move to disable deletes at the resource endpoint. You delete a single document by hitting its own endpoint. Rinse and repeat for multiple documents.

Comment: Thanks Nicola for your fast answer. Are you going to develop someday a feature for delete a list of items?