# Python Eve Conditional / Bulk Delete

Tags: python, eve

From [Nicola's SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35971842/delete-multiple-resource-service-python-eve) and my own testing it seems clear that Eve does not support conditional deletes at resource endpoints.

I know I could use a `GET: "where={...}"` request to the `_ids` and `_etags` of the documents I would like to delete, and then send out a series of requests at each item endpoint to delete them with the `If-Match` header appropriately set to each item's `_etag`:

```
for each item:
    DELETE: http://localhost:5000/items/<item._id>
```

...but I would like to avoid sending out multiple HTTP requests if possible.

One solution may be [predefined database filters](http://python-eve.org/config.html#predefined-database-filters), but these would be static filters where I'd like to dynamically filter deletion depending on some URL parameters. [Pre-event hooks](http://python-eve.org/features.html#pre-request-event-hooks) may be the solution I'm seeking.

Does Eve support bulk deletion? And if not, what is the recommended way to extend Eve's functionality to provide conditional and/or bulk deletes?

Answer (score 0):

I added a pre-event hook to DELETE, and this seems to be working with the tests I've run so far:

```
def add_delete_filters(resource, request, lookup):
    if 'where' in request.args:
        conditions = request.args.getlist('where')
        for cond_str in conditions:
            cond = json.loads(cond_str)
            for attrib in cond:
                lookup[attrib] = cond[attrib]

app = Eve()
app.on_pre_DELETE += add_delete_filters
```